# change of order of derivative and integral in the proof of Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: integration, derivatives, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

When reading the proof of one dimensional Euler-Lagrange equation, e.g. [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation), I stuck myself at one point:
$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\varepsilon}\int_a^b F_\varepsilon \text{d}x = \int_a^b \frac{\text{d}F_\varepsilon}{\text{d}\varepsilon} \text{d}x$.
Why is it possible to change the order of derivative and integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a consequence of the [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) when the limits of integration are constants.